# HTML text expanding all the way to right

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am reading a text document and printing it in my webpage but the text goes all the way to right and i don't want to scroll all the way to right

.[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
        {{text}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to scroll to right and i just want to scroll down and see the entire text. And i cant find a way to do that

Comment: Van you show us the code? Or it’s plain text on the document body?

Comment: Split the string with a character and make a new line every time that character appears.

Comment: Does the {{text}} is simple text or has paragraphs and formatting tags?

Comment: Instead of scrolling all the way to right is there a way to just print down

Comment: It has paragraphs and formatting tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `word-wrap` css

```
p { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) @SyedAli

Comment: @SyedAli please mark this answer as accepted if it helped so others with the same question will get an answer when they search for this :)

Comment: Agreed with @ChiragRavindra

Comment: Accept answer that was helpful because it will help people like me to contribute more @SyedAli

Comment: I tried to accept your answer too buddy it seems i can't

Comment: At first, it was accepted, but don't know what happened later

Answer (score 1):

You can try styling your div to ensure that the text wraps

```css
div.long-text{
 max-width:100%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="long-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te per feugiat tractatos? Sed ei nonumes deserunt adipiscing, at vidit reque vis, in libris eruditi accumsan vix. At duo prima ludus quidam, congue primis cu eum, habeo ocurreret cum ex? Ei postea eruditi tincidunt pri, quo ut maiestatis quaerendum, eum lorem iriure reprimique eu.
<br>
<br>
Loremipsumdolorsitamet,teperfeugiattractatos?Sedeinonumesdeseruntadipiscing,atviditrequevis,inlibriseruditiaccumsanvix.Atduoprimaludusquidam,congueprimiscueum,habeoocurreretcumex?Eiposteaerudititinciduntpri,quoutmaiestatisquaerendum,eumloremiriurereprimiqueeu.Loremipsumdolorsitamet,teperfeugiattractatos?Sedeinonumesdeseruntadipiscing,atviditrequevis,inlibriseruditiaccumsanvix.Atduoprimaludusquidam,congueprimiscueum,habeoocurreretcumex?Eiposteaerudititinciduntpri,quoutmaiestatisquaerendum,eumloremiriurereprimiqueeu.Loremipsumdolorsitamet,teperfeugiattractatos?Sedeinonumesdeseruntadipiscing,atviditrequevis,inlibriseruditiaccumsanvix.Atduoprimaludusquidam,congueprimiscueum,habeoocurreretcumex?Eiposteaerudititinciduntpri,quoutmaiestatisquaerendum,eumloremiriurereprimiqueeu.Loremipsumdolorsitamet,teperfeugiattractatos?Sedeinonumesdeseruntadipiscing,atviditrequevis,inlibriseruditiaccumsanvix.Atduoprimaludusquidam,congueprimiscueum,habeoocurreretcumex?Eiposteaerudititinciduntpri,quoutmaiestatisquaerendum,eumloremiriurereprimiqueeu.Loremipsumdolorsitamet,teperfeugiattractatos?Sedeinonumesdeseruntadipiscing,atviditrequevis,inlibriseruditiaccumsanvix.Atduoprimaludusquidam,congueprimiscueum,habeoocurreretcumex?Eiposteaerudititinciduntpri,quoutmaiestatisquaerendum,eumloremiriurereprimiqueeu.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your text is a made of very long strings that have no spaces. You can fix the wrapping with a css property word-break e.g.:

```html
<head>
...
<style>
 p {
  word-break: break-word;
}
</style>
...
</head>
```

You could try 'break-all' if 'break-word' won't work.